# ifelse文のエラーについて

Tags: python

本日学び始めた初学者です。

```
home="america"
if home =="america":
    print("Hello,america!")
else:
    print("Hello,world")
```

というコードを通したいのですが、
必ずエラーが返ってしまいます。
①そもそも、テキストエディタ（サクラエディタ）に作成したコードを、
python 3.6.5 Shellにコピペしてはいけないのでしょうか。

②1行ずつコピペしても（打っても）else: を打ってエンターキーを押すと
必ずエラーとなってしまいます。（invalid syntax）

上記はどうしてなのでしょうか。
基本的なところで間違っているのかもしれませんが、どう調べてもわからず。。

Comment: 使用しているのは、[IDLE](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/idle.html) のShellですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pythonにおいてはインデントが非常に重要です。書かれたコードの中だとif文(及びelse文)のブロックにインデントが足りないと思います。

```
home = "america"
if home == "america":
    print("Hello, america!")
else:
    print("Hello, world")
```

Comment: 質問のコードにインデントが無いように見えたのは、Markdown によるマークアップに失敗していただけのようです。